# QuickReply WhatsApp Sending through Twilio

Tags: notifications, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-programmable-chat, whatsapp-flows

I'm sending a notification about the order Status Using a WhatsApp Template in Twilio.
I'm adding a 'View More' QuickReply Button where the Customer can reply and see more details about the Order.

The problem is that the Customer can get a few such notifications a day, and I need to know on what particular message they hit 'View More'.

I was thinking of having the button text be 'View More (1263)' (1263 is the order number) and When The Customer clicks it I parse the Button Text in my flow and run the proper HTtp based on the Order.
However, I see the button text needs to be a static string and cannot be a variable.

Any help on how to get this done would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly do that. WhatsApp automatically uses its [reply feature](https://faq.whatsapp.com/3240283752856917/?cms_platform=iphone&helpref=platform_switcher) when the user hits a quick reply action.

This means you can read the [`OriginalRepliedMessageSid`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters) property on the backend to find out which message has been replied to.

Comment: So basically I need to store a Separate Table with a column for the Order Number and a column for the SID and when I get a message look up the Order number for that SID? There is no way I can pass a parameter to a message and get the value of that parameter upon reply?

Comment: Also, I have no feasible way of doing it.
The First message is sent through a REST API, The Reply is handled by a Twilio Flow that is being triggered.
The SID I get from the REST Response is different from what I get from the {{trigger.message.OriginalRepliedMessageSid}}

Comment: Yes, you either need to store the SID->OrderId pair in your backend or fetch the message payload from the logs when you receive a reply (and pull the order ID from the original `body`).
The SIDs should definetly match up. Can you use the [Message Resource API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource) to fetch the `OriginalRepliedMessageSid` and check what you get?

Comment: Ok upon checking the `OriginalRepliedMessageSid` does indeed match the SID of the sent message.
However, the SID of the sent message is not being sent back in the RestAPI Call that I call to send out the message.
The only way I can see the original sent message ID is in the Twilio Dashboard, Which makes it really kinda useless.
Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: How do you mean "The only way I can see the original sent message ID is in the Twilio Dashboard"? You should be able to fetch all messages with the linked Message Resource API

Comment: But I need to know when I sent the message what the SID of that Specific message is

Comment: You should get the SID right away. See the snippet in the top right corner [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging#get-started)

Comment: Can I have the QuickReply be a variable?

Comment: Yes, that is possible

Comment: And how do I send the Value when I call the request?

Comment: I'm afraid this comment section is not the right place for a step-by-step help. Please ask a new question and add the steps you've already done to solve the problem